# How to create a portable SignalR client compatible with "new" SignalR protocol (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-*)?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, .net-core, portability, signalr.client

I'm checking the new SignalR (server) repo: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR and wondering if there is a new/upcoming protocol format? I wanted to create a sample client running on a portable .NET platform (for example netcoreapp1.0). There is a sample client and server (Chat sample), but couldn't make it work. It connects to the server, but throws an exception once I try to send a message (a not really helpful "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.")

So I've checked the source and managed to discover the new message format. Previously, it was this:

```
{"H": "MyHub", "M": "MyHubMethod", "A": ["This is one input argument"], "I": "0"}
```

Assuming the server is being setup this way:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes => routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub"));
```

The client is set up using WebSocket client (from `System.Net.WebSockets.Client`  version 4.3.0 package)

```
var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://myhost:port/myhub/ws"), CancellationToken.None);
```

The new message format is:

```
{
    "Method": "MyCompany.MyNameSpace.MyHub.MyHubMethod",
    "Arguments": ["This is one input argument"],
    "Id": "0"
}
```

That is: `"Method"`, `"Arguments"` and `"Id"` is not shortened anymore and hub is being merged into `"Method"`.

Other parts of the protocol (negotiate, connection management, ping, etc.) is still uncertain for me. Could somebody show some documents?

Comment: Don't forget to add Nuget server for ASP.NET Core dev dependencies:
`https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json`

Comment: Browsing the sources and samples made me realized, that two different endpoints will be supported: Hubs and Sockets

Comment: As of the newer version (2017. January), the `"Method"` is just the method name, no need to add the namespace + class name. It is already obvious from the path, since one hub is being mapped to one path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: SignalR for Asp.NET Core is work in progress and everything is subject to change.

There is no specific format in new SignalR. Rather things are based on what we call 'formatters' and (for hubs) invocation adapters. The idea is that in case of hubs SignalR is working on actual objects describing [invocations](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/InvocationDescriptor.cs) and [invocation results](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/InvocationResultDescriptor.cs). You need to register an implementation of the [`IInvocationAdapter`](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/IInvocationAdapter.cs) that uses formatters to translate data from the wire to invocation descriptors etc. This way SignalR is not tied to any specific format. There will be some default implementations in-the-box - like the one you found for Json but you can provide your own alternative (even for Json) - check the [SocketsSample](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/dev/samples/SocketsSample) - it contains a simplistic support for Protobuf and 'line protocol' where data is being sent in a textual format as lines with some markers and coma separated values.

For now there is no negotiation per se but for non-WebSocket based transports [you need to send an http request to get the connection id](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.TS/Connection.ts#L33-L38). With WebSockets you can connect directly to the server without using any client. (I actually showed a demo recently where I connected a ESP8266 based dev board running lua to a SignalR server over a webSocket and all code was just [this](https://github.com/moozzyk/SocialWeatherClients/blob/e4314df7e974d354861705249074918cfc451ee9/src/lua-client/social-weather.lua) - note that this did not use hubs)